# Kernel - Scheduler : what happens when switching between process

Tags: process, linux-kernel, stack, kernel, scheduler

#### Context:

I don't really understand how the kernel saves the state of a running code when it gets to exceed its time slice.

I don't visualize what happens actually.

#### Question:

1) Where is stored the current running code (and its stack ?) ?

2) When the kernel will "see" the code again, will it just follow an offset and keep going as if nothing happened ?

It is not clear to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the OS but as a general rule there is a block of storage which holds information about each process (usually called the Process Control Block or PCB). This information includes a pointer to the current line of code that is being executed and the contents of registers etc, so the process can start again where it stopped last time.

This block of information is owned by the OS itself not the process so it lives beyond the suspension of the process.

The program code itself is not stored in the PCB - it simply exists in memory or on disk. It can even be shared between processes, for example several processes may be running the same program, each at a different point in the code at any given time and each with their own set of 'variables' or data unique to that process's run of the program. All the OS needs is the variables and the line number or pointer to know where a particular process was in the code when it was suspended, and it can start from that point again.

It is worth noting that any RAM the process was using may or may not be still there when it restarts. In general an OS will try to leave recently used or frequently used RAM chunks (or 'pages') in memory if possible. If it needs to free up space, however, it may swap the 'page' out to disk, but disk access is much, much slower, hence the desire to avoid swapping out memory which is likely to be used again if possible.

In the worst case situation an OS may find it swaps out a process and then very soon the new process need to use some memory which has to be retrieved from disk. It is suspended while this happens as the retrieval take a long time in CPU terms. It may then happen that the next process also very soon finds itself in the same situation. The OS is now spending a lot of its time swapping processes and memory in and out and much less of its time doing real work - this is commonly called 'thrashing'.

Comment: I give you the points for mentioning the PCB , which gave me the basic pointers to the full comprehension of the process, after some readings. Thanks a lot Mick :)

Answer (score 2):

Current code instruction pointer and current stack pointer are stored in `task_struct->ip` and `task_struct->sp` (for x86) and new process's `task_struct->ip` and `task_struct->sp` and are loaded back to `sp` and `ip` registers when [`switch_to()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/core.c?v=3.18#L2367) is called in Linux kernel.

Kernel's `switch_to()` does many things like resetup of EIP, stack, FPU, segment descriptors, debug registers while switching to new process.
Then kernel's `switch_mm()` switch the virtual memory mappings from last process to new process.

Comment: Thanks Miline :) Now I get it completely+1

Comment: Larry, Actual code of switch_to in x86: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/switch_to.h?v=3.18#L27 and in all archs: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=3.18;i=switch_to